# Update tripcolor graph in matplotlib animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have been trying to create an animation in `matplotlib` from the graph `tripcolor`. Let's say I have

```
field = ax.tripcolor(tri, C)
```

How do I change the value of C after each iteration of the animation?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

`field` is guaranteed to be an instance of the `matplotlib.collections.Collection` base class, which helpfully defines a `set_array()` method for just such occasions.

In each iteration of your animation, simply pass the new value of `C` to the `field.set_array()` method. Assuming you use the `FuncAnimation` class for animations, as you probably want to, this reduces to:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)

field = ax.tripcolor(tri, C)

def update_tripcolor(frame_number):
    # Do something here to update "C"!
    C **= frame_number   # ...just not this.

    # Update the face colors of the previously plotted triangle mesh.
    field.set_array(C)

# To triangular infinity and beyond! (Wherever that is. It's probably scary.)
FuncAnimation(fig, update_tripcolor, frames=10)
```

Updating `tri`, on the other hand, is considerably more difficult. While this question doesn't attempt to do so, the perspicacious reader may be curious to learn that you basically have to remove, recreate, and re-add the entire triangle mesh (i.e., `field`) onto this figure's axes. This is both inefficient and painful, of course. (*Welcome to Matplotlib. Population: **you.***)

May the `field.set_array()` be with you.