# set_array() in tripcolor bug?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to `Python` and `matplotlib`, and I recently referenced to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32316063/update-tripcolor-graph-in-matplotlib-animation) to update my `tripcolor` plot. With following data preparation

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri
import math

r = np.zeros((100,100))
t = np.zeros((100,100))
for i in range(0,100):
    for j in range(0,100):
        r[i,j]=i
        t[i,j]=2*math.pi*j/100
x=r*np.cos(t)
y=r*np.sin(t)
z=r*r

xf=x.flatten()
yf=y.flatten()
zf=z.flatten()
triang = tri.Triangulation(xf,yf)
```

If I use `tripcolor` as it is intended,

```
# Works well
p = plt.tripcolor(triang, zf)
```

[correct figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDYXE.png) appears. But, if I try to update *after* creating `tripcolor`,

```
# Not working well
p = plt.tripcolor(triang, xf)
p.set_array(zf)
```

then, [wrong figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9grW.png) appears. Both `xf` and `zf` have identical dimensions.

What am I doing wrong? What is the cause of the problem, and how can I avoid it?

Many thanks in advance.

=========================================================

Update

Thank you all. I actually solved myself.

The key was that I need to assign *color for each area*, which is controlled by `shading` argument, and default value for `tripcolor` is `'flat'`, which is, *color for each vertex*. So, when I plot the first figure, I need to make sure shading is `'gouraud'`, which assigns *color for each area*.

So,

```
p = plt.tripcolor(triang, xf, shading='gouraud')
p.set_array(zf)
```

works as I intended.

Comment: since apparently the linked post was somewhat helpful to you, you could (and should?) upvote the answer that is posted there... even if it only helped you, but did not solve your problem.

Comment: @rll I did upvote that, but since my reputation is low, my feedback is not shown to other people, I'm told.

Comment: Sorry, my bad then :) I was reading your question with more attention, have you try a redraw after setting the array?

Comment: @rll Thank you. I have tried that, and it did work, but too slowly. The code I posted here is just to recreate my problem, and the actual data I am dealing with is quite huge. Moreover, I plan to draw these figures quite often, so I thought I should avoid re-drawing if I could.

Comment: Or, is there a way to *refresh* the figure after such things are done?

Answer (score 0):

The reason

```
p = plt.tripcolor(triang, xf)
p.set_array(zf)
```

is not working as (may be) expected, is the following. In your case `plt.tripcolor()` returns a `PolyCollection`. The `PolyCollection`'s `set_array()` will essentially set the colors of that Collection. However, the underlying triangles will not be changed, such that you end up with the triangles from `xf` but the colors from `zf`.

Since the generation of the tripcolor PolyCollection is quite involved (as it calls `Triangulation` itself) and there probably is no helper function to set the data externally (at least I am not aware of any), the solution might be not to update the tripcolor at all and instead generate a new one.

Is there any reason for you to update? Couldn't you just directly create `p = plt.tripcolor(triang, zf)`?

In case there is a real reason to it, like in an animation or so, an option would be to delete the first tripcolor plot before setting up the next.

```
# create one plot 
p = plt.tripcolor(triang, xf)
#delete this plot (you need both lines actually!!)
p.remove()
del p
#create second plot
p = plt.tripcolor(triang, zf)
```

This is not really efficient, though, and in case someone has a better idea, I'd like to hear about that one as well.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution. Lack of means to control just the data confuses me, though. `triang` is constructed from `xf` and `yf`, which have identical dimensions with `zf`. It only need to change colors, and it seemed plain simple. 

On the other hand, according to your diagnosis, I think, creating with **`zf`**; `p = plt.tripcolor(triang, zf)`, then set the array to **`zf` again**; `p.set_array(zf)` should be fine, but I got that wrong figure again. Similar pattern, just a bit different color.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the source code of `tripcolor` to see what is needed to "just" change the colors. At the end, it doesn't really matter if you do all that by your own or if you delete the object and create a new one. `p.set_array(zf)` is still different from calling `plt.tripcolor(triang, zf)` because there is an intrinsic step of triangulation involved.

Answer (score 0):

To use `set_array()` with `tripcolor(..., shading="flat)`, you need to pass in the values corresponding to the color of each *triangle* rather than each point/vertex. The value representing each triangle is just the mean over the three points making up the triangle. For example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as mtri

# x: shape (n,) array of x values
# y: shape (n,) array of y values
# values: shape (n,) array of z values

# If you have the triangle indices:
# triangles: shape (m, 3) int array of triangle indices

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.tripcolor(x, y, values, triangles=triangles, shading="flat")
new_values = values / 2
tri_values = new_values[triangles].mean(axis=1)
im.set_array(tri_values)

# Or using a Triangulation object, if you don't have triangles to begin with:

tri = mtri.Triangulation(x, y)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.tripcolor(tri, values, shading="flat")
new_values = values / 2
tri_values = new_values[tri.triangles].mean(axis=1)
im.set_array(tri_values)
```